# Select box not allowing me to set default, loading/binding resets value to first item

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I am using knockout in a lot of my project but haven't been using it as an initial form for adding records (I have used it extensively for creating records on UI request and it works great).  If I load a set of defaults via a button click (after the document loads) then everything works great.  If I try to initialize the form at load, I am having trouble assigning defaults to the `select`.

```
<select data-bind="options: statusList, optionsText: function(item){ return item.Status() }, optionsValue: 'Id', value: actualRequest().StatusId"></select>
```

`statusList` is supplied in a database table, the request object is also a database object, created using  a Breezejs call.  I am initializing the values, most of which initialize fine (like datepickers and input defaults) but these `select` elements just aren't initializing the way I thought they should.

A selection from my view model, all appropriate:

```
var em = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceAddress);
function fetchMetaData() {
    if (em.metadataStore.isEmpty()) {
        return em.fetchMetadata();
    }
    return Q.resolve();
};

var load = function () {
    fetchMetaData().done(function () {
        em.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from('Statuses'))
            .then(function (data) { statusList(data.results); })
            .fail(function (error) { logger.error(error.message, "loadStatuses failed during initialization"); });
        // A couple more data calls for other data fills
        setupCreateNew();
    });
};

var setupCreateNew = function() {
    actualRequest(em.createEntity('Submittal', { id: breeze.core.getUuid() }));
    actualRequest().StatusId(2); // 2 is the default value we want
    // more initialization defaults
};

var actualRequest = new ko.observable('');
var statusList = new ko.observable([]);
```

Initialized by

```
app.manageSubmittalRequestViewModel.load();
ko.applyBindings(app.manageSubmittalRequestViewModel, document.getElementById('manageSubmittalRequestId'));
```

The behavior is such that the page initializes, the `actualRequest().StatusId()` as a 2, and by the time the page has has `applyBindings` finished the value for `actualRequest().StatusId()` has changed to a 1.  Any use of the `select` element will change the value to the correct value and this all works fine.  I changed the `value:` attribute to a local (non-initialized) knockout variable that was also initialized during declaration as 2, this also gets reset to a 1 on binding.

Is this something I am doing wrong?  How do I figure out what is resetting this?  I have searched for anything in the View that might be associated that could have a similar name... nothing!

**attached fix**

The fix was changing initialization to this:

```
var load = function () {
    fetchMetaData().done(function () {
        em.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from('Statuses'))
            .then(function (data) { statusList(data.results); })
            .fail(function (error) { logger.error(error.message, "loadStatuses failed during initialization"); })
            .done( function () { setupCreateNew(); });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is a timing issue.  You're not waiting to initialize `statusList` before you you call `setupCreateNew`.  You could try to do something instead like

```
em.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from('Statuses'))
        .then(function (data) { statusList(data.results); })
        .then(function() { setupCreateNew(); })
        .fail(function (error) { logger.error(error.message, "loadStatuses failed during initialization"); });
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: That was basically the problem, although `setupCreated` doesn't return a promise so I put it at the end of the chain using the `done`.  Perfect, thanks.